Find out number of days in a given quarter when date is provided?
I have a data frame with a large number of dates (more than 25 million rows). The sample data looks like this
df <- data.frame(dat = as.Date(c('2015-10-10', '2016-04-04', '2016-01-31', '2017-04-16')))

All dates are in "YYYY-MM-DD"-format.
Goal: I want to add a column that provides the number of days in the quarter in which the date lies.
I understand there are only five unique possibilities here (the number of days in quarters 2, 3 and 4 don't change, and the number of days in quarter 1 depends on whether it is a leap year). I'm currently using a manual approach of extracting the year, then figuring out where it is a leap year, and then assigning a number of days by extracting the quarter. However, this seems like a slow and cumbersome way of doing things. Is there a better and more direct function that can give this answer?

"However, this seems like a slow and cumbersome way of doing things" This is not correct. I diasgree.

Writing a small wrapper (f) is what I would do too.

Fun f
v2 with data.table::year() and data.table::quarter():
f = \(x) {
  stopifnot(inherits(x, "Date"))
  y = data.table::year(x)
  y = y%%4L == 0L & y%%100L != 0L | y%%400L == 0L # see reference 1
  q = data.table::quarter(x)
  d = c(90L:92L, 92L) # see reference 2 
  r = d[q]
  r[q==1L & y] = 91L
  r
}


Execution
> f(df$dat)
[1] 92 91 91 91

> system.time( f(df1$dat) )
   user  system elapsed 
   1.154   0.094   1.260 

Takes ~1.25 [s] on my machine, and appears to be sufficiently fast for 2.5e7 entries in my opinion.

Data
df = data.frame(dat = as.Date(c('2015-10-10', '2016-04-04', '2016-01-31', '2017-04-16')))
df1 = data.frame(dat = as.Date('2015-10-10') + sample(1:365, 2.5e7, TRUE))


Reference

Leap year arithmetic, see 2nd paragraph;
Cumulated days per quarter.


Using lubridate::quarter you can do:
library(lubridate)

as.integer(
  quarter(df$dat, type = "date_last") -
    quarter(df$dat, type = "date_first") + 1
)

#> [1] 92 91 91 91


A data.table solution:
n <- 2.5e7

library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(id=1:n, dat = as.Date('2015-10-10') + sample(1:365, n, TRUE))

setDT(df)

df[, qtr := quarter(dat)][, 
          days := fifelse(qtr>2, 92,
                       fifelse(qtr==2 | qtr==1 & leap_year(dat), 91, 90))]
df
                id        dat   qtr  days
             <int>     <Date> <int> <num>
       1:        1 2016-04-06     2    91
       2:        2 2015-10-24     4    92
       3:        3 2016-04-22     2    91
       4:        4 2016-08-11     3    92
       5:        5 2016-02-05     1    91
      ---                                
24999996: 24999996 2016-07-25     3    92
24999997: 24999997 2016-03-27     1    91
24999998: 24999998 2015-11-20     4    92
24999999: 24999999 2016-06-07     2    91
25000000: 25000000 2015-10-26     4    92

Takes about 10 seconds.
